# Java converting resultset into Entity

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I want to get a List of a specific "Type" like "Person" from my JPAConnector.class via a SQL Query (executeQuery Method).

Everything works fine, but if I don't use a SQL Query like "SELECT p from Person p" to get all, in example

```
SELECT p.name,p.age from Person p
```

then I get as a Resulttype `Object[]` and not a `Person[]`

I know, that if I don't use every field then my Object is not from Person, but if I execute a query like this

```
SELECT p.name AS Name, p.age AS Age, p.location AS Location FROM Person p
```

then I don't get an Person Object back, although I used all fields from Person.

I hope you understand my problem, my English is not good. I'm sorry for that.

Greetings
thunder

Edit: The Background to my Question is, that i want to Average all Columns, where the ID-Column is duplicated ... but that does not has anything to do with my Question ...( only for knowing )

Comment: Are you using Plain SQL or Hibernate.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use constructor queries to get the desired result.

```
SELECT new Person(p.name, p.page) from Person p
```

Make sure your Person entity has the constructor

```
public Person(String name, int age){}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like below in JPA using Entity Manager

```
TypedQuery<Country> query =
      em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p", Person.class);
  List<Person> results = query.getResultList();

then you can access each attribute easily using person as below

  for (Person p : results) {
      System.out.println(p.getName());
//other attributes access
  }
```

Comment: my problem is, that i have to a big database and i want to average specific columns which are duplicated in that table, so i think your wont work.

Comment: you didnt specify in question that .. alright you want the average of some columns from peron table ?

Comment: yes, i edited my Question, sorry that i did not wrote that, but i dont think that this has anything to do with my specific question